# Sony VAIO VPCF22M1E/B ram Upgrade upper limit? (real limit)

Tags: memory, upgrade, sony-vaio

I've got an F series Vaio with the exact model that I depicted in the title field. In its specs, it is implied as 8 GB for maximum memory limit. But a friend of mine with also another f series said me that he upgraded his laptop to 16gb ram without any problem. Have can I make sure that it will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I'm questioning the OEM number, I tend to use the [Crucial Memory Advisor](http://www.crucial.com/store/advisor.aspx), which lets you search for particular systems and tells you how much memory the system supports.

According to Crucial, [the limit is 8 gigs](http://www.crucial.com/store/listparts.aspx?model=VAIO%20VPCF22M1E) . . .

Yes Crucial is a third-party, but it's obviously in Crucial's best interest to make sure this information is accurate, i.e. they want to encourage customers to get RAM if the system will support it and not over sell RAM (which will lead to returns, and thus lowered profits).  They offer a guarantee for the tool as well:

> 100% compatibility - guaranteed!
>
> Without a doubt, compatibility is the most important factor in buying a memory upgrade for your laptop or computer. Your RAM must be compatible with your system — or your system just won't work. With so many variations in memory, it's important to understand just exactly what will work — and what won't — in your system. Using the Memory Advisor or Scanner on Crucial.com is the best way to ensure compatibility. 100% guaranteed. Or your money back.